# upstream power level causing modem disconnects and reboots

Tags: cable-modem

I read an answer for this question from 2012. The reason I ask is that the Comcast connection troubleshooting site states that upstream power levels above 50 dBm will cause disconnects and reboots.

Mine is at 55-57 and disconnects quite a bit. It's very annoying. Even if you don't think this is the problem, is there a way to reduce the power level?

Comment: My cable company (TWC business class) installed a filter to the back if our modem to address this same situation.

Comment: Comcast will need to service this for you, there is nothing you can do to help yourself.  The problem is it's hard to get them to send a truck... they want to reboot the modem and get you off the phone.  I've discovered that the best method is to threaten to disconnect your service and switch isp's (TV too) unless they fix your service.   FWIW, no two people with the exact same problem will likely have the same fix.  The variables include amplifers up stream from you on the main line, any amplifier they have installed at your premise, and other issues as small as nicked cable or bad connectors